# Why does Spark write always the same amount of files to HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hdfs, spark-streaming

I have a Spark streaming application written in Scala running in CDH. The application reads data from Kafka and writes the data to HDFS. Before writing data to HDFS, I execute `partitionBy`, so the data is written partitioned. Every partition gets 3 files upon writing. I also use `coalesce` to control number of partitions of my data. My expectation is that number of partitions set by `coalesce` command will set the number of files in the output directory in HDFS, however the amount of files is always 3 despite of amount of partitions set by `coalesce` command. I tried running with 3 executors and with 6 executers, but still number of files in each partition is 3.

This is how I write data to HDFS:

```
//Some code
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
             ssc,
             PreferConsistent,
             Subscribe[String,String](topics, kafkaParams))
val sparkExecutorsCount = sc.getConf.getInt("spark.executor.instances", 1)
//Some code
stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
    if(!rdd.isEmpty()) {
        val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
        val data = rdd.map(kafkaData => (getKey(kafkaData.value()), kafkaData.value()))
        val columns = Array("key", "value")
        data.toDF(columns: _*).coalesce(sparkExecutorsCount)
            .write.mode(SaveMode.Append)
            .partitionBy("key").text(MY_PATH)

       stream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
    } else {
        //handle empty RDD
    }
}
```

Please advise how to make my spark applications write another amount of files to output directory. Thank you

Comment: Is 3, the number of total files or number of folders under the MY_PATH. Could you post the hdfs dfs -ls -R MY_PATH ?

Comment: @alexeipab 3 is the number of files in each sub-directory (partition) under MY_PATH. It looks like this:
`MY_PATH/key=1
MY_PATH/key=1/file1.txt
MY_PATH/key=1/file2.txt
MY_PATH/key=1/file3.txt
MY_PATH/key=2
MY_PATH/key=2/file1.txt
MY_PATH/key=2/file2.txt
MY_PATH/key=3/file3.txt`

Comment: A couple of addition questions: 1) was sparkExecutorsCount == 3 or 1 when you produced the output? 2) What are the timestamps for each file, are they the same for all files?

Comment: 1) I tried with sparkExecutorsCount == 3 and sparkExecutorsCount == 6. The output was the same. I never tried with sparkExecutorsCount == 1. 2) Yes, all files have the same timestamp

Answer (score 0):

**coalesce** does not reshuffle data on the key, it concatenates partitions without redistributing records across partitions. In your example **partitionBy** is not called on the Dataframe, but on the DataFrameWriter which is returned by the **.write** function. In this case it looks like column **key** has 3 values, hence 3 folders (key=1, key=2, key=3) and 3 files in each folder with the same timestamp can be explained by the Dataframe having at least 3 partitions, as there will be a writer per partition running which has to output into 3 folders (key=1, key=2, key=3). I would suspect that "sparkExecutorsCount == 6" had no impact may be because Kafka provided you with just 3 partition and in this case coalesce has no affect.

To go down just to 1 file per key folder you can try **coalesce(1)** or instead of it use **repartition($"key")** and keep the existing **paritionBy**

```
data.toDF(columns: _*).repartition($"key")
        .write.mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .partitionBy("key").text(MY_PATH)
```

or

```
data.toDF(columns: _*).repartition(sparkExecutorsCount, $"key")
        .write.mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .partitionBy("key").text(MY_PATH)
```

Comment: The file structure I provided was only partial: because "key" has 1000 values and I did not specify them all. Sorry if my printout of files structure misled you. I don't know whether DataFrame had 3 partitions. How can I check and control this? Kafka provided me the same amount of partitions as sparkExecutorsCount. I control this manually when I create Kafka topic.